# Question about Fourier cosine series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I'm trying to find Fourier cosine series for function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
        \frac{\pi}{2}-x,\quad &\text{if } x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
        \pi,\quad &\text{if } x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]
        \end{cases}$$
in $[0,\pi]$.

I found coefficients
$$b_k=0,\quad a_0=\frac{5\pi}{4}\quad \text{and}\quad a_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{2} + k\pi\sin k\pi - k\pi\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}}{k^2}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, but I don't know how to simplify $a_k$ to write cosine series as
$$\frac{5\pi}{4}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ ...\ \cos kx$$
and investigate pointwise convergence in $[0,\pi]$.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Finding the coefficients amounts to finding the series. For convergence use the Dirichlet condition

Answer (score 1):

$a_k=0$ if $k$ is a multiple of $4$. $a_k=\frac 1 {\pi j^{2}}$ if $k=2j$ with $j$ odd.
$a_k=\frac 1 {\pi} \frac { 1-(2j-1)\pi(-1)^{j+1}} {(2j-1)^{2}}$ if $k=2j-1$.

In all cases $|a_k| \leq \frac C {k^{2}}$ for some $C$ so $\sum |a_k| <\infty$. This imlies that the Fourier series converges to $f$ at very point.

I have just used basic properties sine and cosine functions.